# Avoiding HTML duplication with mustache templates

Tags: mustache

If I have several components (individual '.mustache' files) which I want to import as partials into a main template and those components have an identical containing `<div>`, can you code it in a way that avoids having repetition across the components?

```
<div class="Component">
    <h3>Component One</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="Component">
    <h3>Component Two</h3>
    <p>Dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

The common container `<div class="Component">` is duplicated in each file which seems inefficient but I'm not sure how to avoid the duplication.

So I have a template called 'home.mustache' and it has:

```
<div class="Main">
    Some content
</div>
<div class="Sidebar">
    {{> component1 }}
    {{> component2 }}
</div>
```

I guess something that in my head is like this, but the compontent-container spits out opening and closing markup (then I can remove the container from each component):

```
<div class="Sidebar">
    {{# component-container }}
        {{> component1 }}
    {{/ component-container }}
    {{# component-container }}
        {{> component2 }}
    {{/ component-container }}
</div>
```

Comment: I may not fully understand your question, but it seems to me that you could just wrap your partials with your container div inside of `home.mustache`: `<div class="Sidebar"><div class="Component">{{> component1 }}{{> component2 }}</div></div>` (forgive the lack of formatting here). Does this achieve what you want?

Comment: Each component needs the `<div class="component">` wrapper.  So each partial would need that div in it.  If that class changed, I'd have to change it in multiple places.  With the code you've mentioned, both components would live inside one `<div class="component">`

Comment: I misunderstood then. I thought you wanted both component 1 and 2 inside the same container. I think I now understand.